# LT SPICE Simulation Error OPA1664 and AD8067

Tags: ltspice

I simulated  circuit which consist of a trans impedance amplifier ,some multistage amplifiers and filters.In my first circuit TIA used is AD8067 and for other parts I used TL074 op amp from TI.This circuit was working perfectly in LT spice.
After this I replaced TL074 with OPA1664 and TIA remains the same.But for this circuit I am getting an error as shown below.

**Singular matrix:  Check nodes d:u3:u2:1#int1 and u1:13
   Iteration No. 2
Fatal Error: Singular matrix:  check nodes d:u3:u2:1#int1 and u1:13
   Iteration No. 2**

Circuit diagram and screen shot of error file are attached along with this mail.
 [image]

I connected a 1GIG Resistance from non inverting point to ground.But the problem still exists.

I am attaching the circuit files along with this mail.Circuit 1.Its op is connected to ip of circuit 2.[image: Circuit 2 its op is connected to ip of circuit 3![][1]]

[image]

---

I connected a 1GIG Resistance from non inverting point to ground.But the problem still exists.
I am attaching the circuit files along with this mail.Circuit 1.Its op is connected to ip of circuit 2.[image: Circuit 2 its op is connected to ip of circuit 3![][1]]

[image]

Comment: Your circuit diagram is not readable. Can you read it ?

Answer (score 1):

"Singular Matrix" issues are usually resolved by adding a 1GIG resistor to ground. It means "a current is too small to calculate." Try adding one from net d:u3:u2:1 to ground. (I can't read it either.)

Comment: LTSpice is funny about "1GIG." It must be typed as "1GIG", not "1G". Try that.